# How can I disable back button in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have tried to disable back button in browser but it just reloading the page to the path="/"

How can I disable back button of the browser, so when user clicks it nothing happens??

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    history.listen((newLocation, action) => {
      if (action === "POP") {
        history.go(0);
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/main/component1" component={Component1} />
            <Route path="/main/component2" component={Component2} />
            <Route path="/main/component3" component={Component3} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't really block the back button of the browser, but you can prevent transitions. https://reactrouter.com/web/example/preventing-transitions

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it using react-router-dom**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();
history.replace("/login");
```